# Confirm app installation?

Tags: android

My app is installing an APK like so:

```
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
PendingIntent pint = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, install, 0);
```

The PendingIntent is passed to a notification as the Content Intent so tapping it will install the APK. This works and brings up the system app installer interface with the permissions and all that. The user can cancel it or back out of it. How can I know if the install actually happened or if it was aborted?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but I imagine, you could use a Receiver with an intent-filter for ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

For ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Comment: @LokiSinclair I'll try that when I get a chance. You should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine, you could use a Receiver with an intent-filter for ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED